# Logistic equation - How to go from continuous form to discrete form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method, discrete-calculus

Logistic equation in continuous form:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t} = ry(1 - ay)$  (Autonomous Differential Equations and Population Dynamics, equation 6 in Boyce Diprima's book, eleventh Edition)

Considering a = 1:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t} = ry(1 - y)$

Logistic equation in discrete form:

$y_{n + 1} = ry_n(1-y_n)$ ([Logistic map - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) )

How to prove, or how to obtain one model from another ? I mean, for example, how can I reach the discrete equation starting from continuous equation and prove that both are equivalents ?

Comment: They're not at all equivalent. The differential equation has very nicely behaved solutions while, as Wikipedia explains, the discrete equation exhibits quite complicated behavior.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I'm not saying that they are equal. But, I guess the discrete form came from the continuous form, or can be obtained by the continuous form by discretization. The different behavior comes from the quantization process

Comment: The discretization of the differential equation is $y_{n+1} - y_n = ry_n(1 - y_n)$; you replace the derivative with a finite difference. This gives $y_{n+1} = y_n(r + 1 - ry_n)$ which is similar to but not quite the same as the logistic equation. Then you can massage it into the logistic equation via a suitable rescaling.

Comment: How to do this massage it into the logistic equation via a suitable rescaling ?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $r$ and then take $z_n = ry_n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, I did, and this way I got $ry_{n+1} = z_n(r + 1 - z_n)$ is It right ? What would be the next step ?

Comment: You get $z_{n+1} = z_n(r+1 - z_n)$. This is a logistic equation but with a modified parameter $r + 1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But doing this I will have a different equation, so the discrete logistic equation as it is used is not a discretization of the ODE version ?

Comment: Very strictly speaking, no. But the only thing that's different is that the parameter in one doesn't correspond exactly to the parameter in the other. That $+1$ is not a big deal.